# Share your suggested edits with others so they'll approve or reject

Tags: facebook

When you enter Facebook Pages, Places, etc. somewhere in the top buttons there's usually a way to suggest edits.

Those suggestions appear for edit lovers who know about the existence of https://www.facebook.com/editor/ - this page pop ups random suggestions that can be approved or rejected on the spot. There's therefore about zero chance of your own suggestions ever dropping the pending status.

My question is - can you avoid the randomness and somehow share specific suggestions to increase the likelihood of their approval or rejection?

Before you answer, keep in mind there are lots of *closed* Facebook Groups with the goal of "requesting others to review edits". What is going on in these mostly geographically local groups and how do they review specific edits?

Comment: I'd think that would be rather unlikely, and for the reasons you've already expressed. Imagine a group of four or five friends who conspire to fill the descriptions of places with dick jokes. The integrity of the data submitted by the public is enhanced by having strangers vetting the submissions; if people could cherry-pick what to suggest, especially from people they know, they information would be much less reliable.

Comment: That's why I wonder what's going on in these groups. If it was completely impossible, there wouldn't be so many groups of this type.